# Apache: Issue to display accented character with Content-type:text/plain

Tags: apache, debian, diacritics

I upgraded my Debian from Squeeze to Wheezy.

Then I noticed that when HTTP headers contains "`Content-type: text/plain`", Apache does not display the body. (It's not a navigator (browser?) issue as source shows it empty and I tried with all navigators.)

When I set "`Content-type: text/html`", all body is correctly displayed.

I give an example:

1. I send email in PHP with text/text ⟶ body is not displayed

   ```
   $header  = "From:noreply@anydomain.com\n";

   $header.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";

   $header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

   mail('email@mysquirrelmailserver', 'subject', 'é' , $header);
   ```
2. I send email in PHP with text/html ⟶ body is displayed

   ```
   $header  = "From:noreply@anydomain.com\n";

   $header.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";

   $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

   mail('email@mysquirrelmailserver', 'subject', 'é' , $header);
   ```

Squirrelmail is just an example.
For example, with net2ftp editor, all files containing accented character cannot be edited (body is empty) - but they can be viewed and correctly displayed with accent.

I also repeat all was correctly working in Squeeze version.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i finally got it

wheezy upgraded php to 5.4

but in 5.4 php function htmlentities  does not have same behavior than 5.3 which may be a big problem to deal with

To solve in followed 
http://blog.wpkg.org/2013/06/20/downgrading-to-php-5-3-on-debian-wheezy-7-0/